# applying css to actionlink mvc 4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

This seemed a simple task but I can not work out how to apply css class to actionlink..
I have put a css class at the bottom of site.css located in content folder as follows. All examples ive seen says this should work.. but nothing happens.

this is link ive followed line by line and still nothing happened.
    http://www.devcurry.com/2011/03/aspnet-mvc-use-css-on-htmlactionlink.html

im using mvc4 template and modifiying as needed.

```
.mybutton
{
  color:Lime;   
}

foreach (string str in ViewBag.ServerNames)
{

    <ul>
        <img src="../../Content/Images/my_computer.png" alt="Computer Name"/>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(linkText: str.ToString(), actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Customer",
          routeValues: new { conName = str.ToString() }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mybutton" })</li>
    </ul>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your CSS rules wrapped in a `style` tag. Change it to this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mybutton
    {
        color:Lime;   
    }
</style>
```

---

Your `foreach` loop renders each link with this HTML:

```
<a class="mybutton" href="/MVCApp/Customer/Index?conName=cat">cat</a>
```

Therefore, we must assume you aren't linking to the CSS file correctly, or perhaps its an inheritance issue. Can you post a JSFiddle with your entire CSS and HTML from the page?

Comment: See the new part of my answer above. Its prob a CSS/HTML issue, not an MVC one.